# Can I know when a wallet was created?

Tags: wallets, blockchain, timestamp

Is it possible to see the creation date of a wallet? If so, where? Is this information publicly recorded in the blockchain? I don't seem to find it. For instance, consider [this](https://tzscan.io/tz1XfAjZyaLdceHnZxbMYop7g7kWKPut4PR7) random address (taken from endorsements to a recent block). Can we know when it was created?

Comment: What do you mean by "wallet" and "create"?

Comment: @Tom When a `tz1` address (an originated account) [was created](https://tezos.gitlab.io/master/introduction/howtouse.html#originated-accounts-and-contracts).

Comment: tz1 addresses are not originated accounts. A tz1 address is created by generating a new secret key. This can happen in secret, obviously, and so we can never know when it happened. Clearly this is not what you're asking about?

Comment: @Tom I meant an implicit account. Maybe I do not know enough and this site can help me understanding better? Maybe I do mean generating a new secret key.

Answer (score 5):

My suggestion would be using tzscan API.

For example **checking all activations until you find a match**

something like this:

```
index = 0
loop while true
  GET https://api1.tzscan.io/v1/operations?type=Activation&p=${index++}&number=50
  compare each item
end loop
```

**It has a timestamp for each activation**

---

***Correct way of doing it with tzscan***

Replace `<public_key_hash>` below with the `tz1` address:

```
https://api5.tzscan.io/v1/operations/<public_key_hash>?type=Reveal
```

So, your example address is [here](https://api5.tzscan.io/v1/operations/tz1XfAjZyaLdceHnZxbMYop7g7kWKPut4PR7?type=Reveal)

Comment: So activation time is the creation date? And is that in the blockchain?

Comment: Yes, but you need to have a copy of the full blockchain if you want to access old activations or do like tzscan that sniffs everything from the chain and stores it on a database.